Old martial arts film with a Shaolin monk in disguise
I wanted to ask about the title of an old martial arts film. 
I guess the film is from the 70s or 80s. 
The story was set in a village, where a mysterious stranger arrived. 
Throughout the film he fought occasionally with minions of the main villain and one or two of the villagers saw how strong he was and began to hang out with him but for him they were just a nuisance.
During the final sequence of the movie the good guy was in a maze or a dungeon, where he had to overcome many booby traps on his way to the final chamber. There the bad guy was expecting him. Just before the fight commenced the good guy removed his wig, after the villain called him by his real name. It was revealed that the bad guy stole a Shaolin artifact (a box with something in it) some time ago, and the stranger was a Shaolin monk, who wanted to get it back.
After a long and grueling battle the bad guy died, while the good guy was heavily wounded. In the end he picked up (along with his two "comrades") the box, opened it but it was empty! The movie ended as the monk threw away the box in disbelief... 
I vaguely remember that the title was something like "Fists and courage"... 
That’s all I can remember for the film. If anyone finds it familiar and have any ideas – please share your thoughts... 

You were close: You're looking for Fists and Guts from 1979. From an online synopsis:

In this vintage martial arts-adventure, a warrior (Gordon Liu), searching for a criminal on the run from the law, discovers a gang of thieves who plan to steal an irreplaceable Jade Buddha. He leaps into action to save the Buddha, but he discovers a variety of bizarre traps and gifted martial arts fights are laying in wait for him. 

Here's the very end of the movie, where the protagonist removes his wig, fights the villain and finds out that the container is actually empty:




Shame on me for not remembering that Gordon Liu plays the main character. :D
Thank you for the answer, Walt. I really appreciate it.
